# Transform Int to Option[Int]

Tags: scala

This is my code:

```
package net.claritysales.api.helper

import net.claritysales.api.models.UserEntity

import scala.util.Random


trait TestData {


      def userInfo(
          id : Long = randomLong(),
          username : String = randomString(),
          password : String = randomString()
      ) : UserEntity = {
      var user : UserEntity = new UserEntity(
          id = id, //Error is Long and recived Optional[Long]
          username = username,
          password = password)
      return user}

  def randomString(): String = Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString("")

  def randomLong(): Long =  Random.nextLong()
}
```

and UserEntity:

```
 case class UserEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, username: String, password: String) {
  require(!username.isEmpty, "username.empty")
}
```

and the error message: **Type mismatch, expected: Option[Long], actual: Long**

How do I transform Optional[Long] to Long ? Id is Optiona[Long] randomLong() and id must is Long. Thanks!

Comment: That depends greatly on what you want to happen if your option is `None`. PS: In the code you've shown us, there's nothing that has the type `Option[Int]`. Did you perhaps post the wrong code? Also please post the exact error message.

Comment: Thank you! and if there is an Option in the UserEntity, I already saw it ...

Comment: I edit the question to clarify the details mentioned, thank!

Comment: `Option`, or `Optional`? which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly the issue in your code is, but I'll cover the usual ways to deal with `Option`. `Option` solves the same problem that Java's `null` solves, but it does so in a way that is orders of magnitude better, safer, and easier to work with. So I'm going to work with a hypothetical function here, that just received a `Option[A]`. The question you need to ask yourself is: what does it mean if I get a `None`? Scala forces you to ask this question, where making all class types implicitly nullable (as in Java) does not.

## Option 1: Propagate the Error Quietly

Perhaps `None` indicates a failure in the place where we got the `A` from. Something went wrong, the random generator failed, maybe we divided by zero. Then we want to indicate that we failed. So, in this case, we change our function's return type from `A` to `Option[A]` and return a `None`.

In Java, this would look like this.

```
if (arg == null)
    return null;
return doSomething(arg);
```

In Scala,

```
arg map { x => doSomething(x) }
```

If `arg` is `None`, then this returns `None`. If `arg` contains a value, it runs `doSomething` on the value and returns the result, inside an `Option[A]`.

## Option 2: `None` indicates Different Behavior

Perhaps `None` indicates, in some sense, that we want the function to behave differently. In Java, this would look something like this.

```
if (arg != null) {
    return doSomething(arg);
} else {
    return doSomethingElse();
}
```

In Scala, we do this in a typesafe way.

```
arg match {
  case None => doSomethingElse()
  case Some(x) => doSomething(x) // Note that x is A, not Option[A]
}
```

## Option 3: `None` is Just a Default

Sometimes `None` just indicates that we want to use a default value. If we're adding up a bunch of numbers, and some of them might be `None`, we want `None` to equate to the numerical value `0` so that it doesn't alter our results.

In Java, we might write,

```
int x = 0;
if (arg != null)
    x = arg;
return doSomething(x);
```

In Scala, we can do this more concisely with `getOrElse`.

```
doSomething(arg.getOrElse(0))
```

## Option 4: Propagate the Error Loudly

Maybe `None` is really bad in our case. Perhaps it's an error in the invoked code that we're just not at all equipped to handle. Perhaps our function is just *waaaay* too important, and if it fails then everything else is forfeit. Then we can raise an exception. Note that this approach is not very idiomatic in Scala, so it should be used very sparingly, only when it doesn't make sense to do any of the above.

In Java,

```
if (arg == null)
  throw new RuntimeException("Oops!");
return doSomething(arg);
```

In Scala,

```
arg match {
  case None => sys.error("Oops!")
  case x => doSomething(x)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood it even more! I'm starting with the language!

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that you have an `Option[Int]` and need an `Int` (as you've claimed in the title and body of your question). It's that you have an `Int` and need an `Option[Int]`. This is because `userInfo` takes an `Int`, but `UserEntity` takes an `Option[Int]`.

To solve this problem, you can simply pass `Some(id)` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use get or else, i dont know in your case what give in None case

```
var user : UserEntity = new UserEntity(
      id = id.getOrElse(0l)
      username = username,
      password = password)
  return user}
```